# Eigen : solving A=xB (Assert failed)

Tags: c++, matlab, eigen

i'm trying to convert some matlab code to C++

I'm using [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org) which is a fantastic library (try it if you don't know)

but i'm trying to convert this line :

```
x = B/A
```

with

```
B = rand(7,20);
A = rand(1,20);
```

The code in Matlab **works with no problem** and it returns an array (1x7)

With Eigen (here is the code:

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic> A(7,20);
Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic> B(1,20);
cout<< A.colPivHouseholderQr().solve(B);
```

i got an **assertion failed :**

> rhs.rows() == dec.rows()

so it seems i can only solve the system for Matrices of the **same number of rows**?

My math is a bit limited, but is there a way to do the solving **anyhow**?

i've also tried this code instead :

```
cout << (A.transpose() * A).ldlt().solve(A.transpose() * B)
```

and

```
cout <<A.jacobiSvd(ComputeThinU | ComputeThinV).solve(B)
```

**thanks**

Jeff

Comment: Hmm, the [documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1ColPivHouseholderQR.html#afbe1cd1202964011ae7e7411577749a0) says that "The case where b is a matrix is not yet implemented."

Comment: To respect matrix dimension you're not suppose to do `Ax = b ` != `(7x20) x ( 1 x 7) = (1 x 20)`. But `(20x7)(7x1) = (20x1)` ? Except your system is `xA = b`, that working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the problem:

In MATLAB, `B/A` [solves the equation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html) `xA=B`.

In Eigen, the `solve` method solves the equation `Ax=B`. In MATLAB, this would be expressed as `x = A\B`.

These are very different - matrix multiplication is *not* commutative!

In general, the matrix product `Ax` has the same number of rows as `A` and the same number of columns as `x`. Therefore, for the equation `Ax=B` to make sense, `A` must have the same number of rows as `B` (this is where your assertion error came from).

Now the two are related by the equation `B/A = (A'\B')'`, so you can do something like (untested code)

```
Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic> C = A.transpose().fullPivLu().solve(B.transpose());
cout << C.transpose();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you look to [mldivide](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html)

For a system : `Ax = b` to solve it you need to do : `x = A\B`.

So in your case you're trying to solve : `xA = b`.

That why in eigen you're matrix dimension isn't fitting.